# xlsx array of objects containing arrays - json to excel file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, xlsx

I'm building an application for workout rotuines, where I want the user to be able to download an excel file of the selected program.

Currently I'm having the data formatted as an array of objects where each object contains the workout date as key, and all the exercise objects in an array. That is `[{2022-05-30: [{exercise: bench, reps: 10, sets: 3}, {exercise: legs, reps: 5, sets: 5}]}, {…}, {…}, {…}]` or for an even clearer overview:

```
[
    {
        "2022-05-30": [
            {
                "number": "1",
                "exercise": "Squat",
                "reps": "6",
                "sets": "3",
                "rest": "300"
            },
            {
                "number": "2",
                "exercise": "Deadlift",
                "reps": "6",
                "sets": "2",
                "rest": "300"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2022-05-31": [
            {
                "number": "1",
                "exercise": "Bench press",
                "reps": "6",
                "sets": "3",
                "rest": "300"
            },
            {
                "number": "2",
                "exercise": "Primary Upper Back Exercise",
                "reps": "6",
                "sets": "3",
                "rest": "120"
            },
            {
                "number": "3",
                "exercise": "Shoulder Exercise",
                "reps": "6",
                "sets": "1",
                "rest": "60"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When I try to save this however it only saves the keys of each object in the array, so when downloading the excel file the output in the excel file will be just:

[image: excel output]

Ideally I would want each date as the header followed by all the exercises for that date.

Here is the code that I'm using to convert it:

```
import * as FileSaver from "file-saver";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

 const exportToCSV = () => {
    const formattedData = fromatData(csvData); //here I get the formatted data as shown above in the question
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(formattedData);
    const wb = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ["data"] };
    const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "array" });
    const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension);
  };
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-dew-n3fr85?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you create codesandbox for this?

Comment: Sure, here you go. Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-dew-n3fr85?file=/src/App.js @Nemanja

Answer (score 0):

A json structure like this:

```
export const program = [
  {
    date: "2022-05-30",
    number: "1",
    exercise: "Squat",
    reps: "6",
    sets: "3",
    rest: "300"
  },
  {
    date: "2022-05-31",
    number: "1",
    exercise: "Bench press",
    reps: "6",
    sets: "3",
    rest: "300"
  }
];
```

Produces this output:

[image]

Whereas, if you want to convert rows-to-columns, you have to transpose the matrix:

```
  ...
  const transpose = (a) =>
    Object.keys(a[0]).map((c) => {
      let ret = a.map((r) => r[c]);
      ret.unshift(c);
      return ret;
    });

  const exportToCSV = () => {
    const transpData = transpose(program);
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(transpData);
    ...
```

And the output in this case becomes:

[image]

For some reason, an extra line is added at the top, take a look here on how to remove it:
https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/352